# WebService return 0 or error

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I would like recover data on my database but my link with the database don't work .
When I call my WebService without parameters , it's ok. 
But when I try with parameters doesn't work .

My Class for call my webService :

```
 public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://webgarda20170508110006.azurewebsites.net/Add";

    public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "Add";

    public  final String NAMESPACE = "http://webgarda20170508110006.azurewebsites.net/";

    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://webgarda20170508110006.azurewebsites.net/Garda.asmx";
    public CallSoap()
    {
    }
    public String Call(int a,int b)
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
      pi.setName("a");
        pi.setValue(a);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi=new PropertyInfo();
       pi.setName("b");
       pi.setValue(b);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response=null;
        try
        {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = envelope.getResponse();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            response=exception.toString();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

[link for the detail of my werbservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2GZE.jpg)

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: My settings are not read by my webServices. It does not affect the two variables. For my webService the variables are null and return 0. It returns the same result as if I send nothing.

Comment: So the input parameters (a and b) are ignored?

Comment: Yes , it's very strange

Comment: Maybe it's something in the WebService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem :

Change

```
public  final String NAMESPACE="http://webgarda20170508110006.azurewebsites.net/";
```

To

```
public  final String NAMESPACE="http://webgarda20170508110006.azurewebsites.net";
```